# How to retrieve an IQ response

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

I am trying to automate some xmpp server tests. I send a xml stanza to xmpp server and verify the response. I can successfully send the stanza but I am having trouble retrieving the response.

I am using Smack 4.1.8 api.

This is the stanza that I am sending:

```
<iq id='123' from='rmorgan@xmppserver.domain.net' to='sandbox@xmppserver.domain.net/resource' type='get'>
<control xmlns='http://domain.com/powertalk/control/2.0'>
<point id='00000000/relay_1A' />
<point id='00000000/relay_2A' />
</control>
</iq>
```

When I send this using PSI client I get the following in return:

```
<iq from="sandbox@xmppserver.domain/resource" type="result" to="rmorgan@xmppserver.domain/resource" id="17">
<control xmlns="http://domain.com/powertalk/control/2.0">
<point val="0" id="00000000/relay_1A" ts="2016-08-30T15:52:41.068308Z"/>
<point val="0" id="00000000/relay_2A" ts="2016-08-30T15:52:41.148337Z"/>
</control>
</iq>
```

That is what I want to retrieve.

What I actually receive is:

```
    <iq to='rmorgan@xmppserver.domain.net/resource' from='rmorgan@xmppserver.domain.net' id='c8QbM-8' type='result'>
<query xmlns='jabber:iq:roster'></query>
</iq>
```

Here is my code. I think I have to do some sort of custom IQ provider but the examples I'm finding are mostly for Smack 3.x and are not valid.

```
        AbstractXMPPConnection mConnection = this.getConnection();
        try
        {
            final IQ iq = new IQ("control","http://domain.com/powertalk/control/2.0") 
            {
                @Override
                protected IQChildElementXmlStringBuilder getIQChildElementBuilder(IQChildElementXmlStringBuilder xml) 
                {
                    xml.rightAngleBracket();
                    xml.halfOpenElement("point");
                    xml.attribute("id", "00000000/relay_1A");
                    xml.append(" />");
                    xml.halfOpenElement("point");
                    xml.attribute("id", "00000000/relay_2A");
                    xml.append(" />");

                    return xml;
                }
            };
            iq.setStanzaId("123");
            iq.setFrom("rmorgan@xmppserver.domain.net");
            iq.setType(IQ.Type.get);
            iq.setTo("sandbox@xmppserver.domain.net/resource");
            mConnection.sendStanza(iq);

            // Receive the packet
            IQ iqReceived = (IQ)collector.nextResult(50000);

            // Stop queuing results
            collector.cancel();

            System.out.println("Sent:     " + iq.toXML());
            System.out.println("Received: " + iqReceived.toXML());
            System.out.println("Collector size = " + collector.getCollectedCount()); //returns 0
            System.out.println("collector pollResult = " + collector.pollResult()); //returns null
            System.out.println("collector StanzaFilter = " + collector.getStanzaFilter()); //returns: StanzaIdFilter: id=123
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I suggest looking at Smack's source code. The XMPP ping code is a simple example how to send IQ pings and listen for the results.

Comment: are you using openfire custom plugin for this communication ?

Comment: from what i understand of ping, it just returns true/false. I'm not seeing a way to retrieve the IQ result from the server. Can you explain how I would do that and return the result that PSI client does in my example above?

Comment: I'm not using any custom plugins

Comment: i have done but i have used plugin for communication

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. So if anyone is interested, here is my solution.
This is my test calling my code.

```
  XmppMethods command = new XmppMethods();

  String result;
  result = command.sendXMLCommand("123", "get", "00000000/relay_1A", "00000000/relay_2A");

  System.out.println("result = " + result);
```

sendXMLCommand method:

```
public String sendXMLCommand(String packetID, String type, String... points) throws IOException, XMPPException
    {
        ListIQ result = null;
        try
        {
            this.makeConnection();
            final XMPPConnection mConnection = this.getConnection();
            ServiceProviders.Register_Providers(ProviderManager.getInstance());
            this.login();
            IQConnectionRequest iq = new IQConnectionRequest(packetID, type, points);

            PacketFilter filter = new AndFilter(new PacketIDFilter(iq.getPacketID()),
                    new PacketTypeFilter(IQ.class));
            PacketCollector collector = mConnection.createPacketCollector(filter);

            mConnection.sendPacket(iq);

            result = (ListIQ)collector.nextResult(50000);

            collector.cancel(); 


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            this.disconnect();
        }
        return result.toXML();

    }
```

IQConnectionRequest

```
public class IQConnectionRequest extends IQ 
{        
    protected String[] points;

    public String[] getPoints() 
    {
        return points;
    }

    public void setPoints(String... points)
    {
        this.points = points;
    }


    @Override
    public String getChildElementXML() 
    {
        String body = "<control xmlns=\"http://domain_name.com/powertalk/control/2.0\">";

        for (int i = 0; i<this.points.length; i++)
        {
            body += "<point id='" + this.points[i] + "' />";
        }

        body += "</control>";

        return body;

    }

    /**
     * Create new IQ Connection Request
     *
     * @param username
     * @param password
     */
    public IQConnectionRequest(String packetID, String type, String... points) 
    {
        this.setFrom("user@xmppserver.domain.com");
        this.setTo("user@xmppserver.domain.com/resource");
        this.setPacketID(packetID);
        if (type.toLowerCase().equals("get"))
            this.setType(IQ.Type.GET);
        else if (type.toLowerCase().equals("set"))
            this.setType(IQ.Type.SET);
        else
            System.out.println("ERROR: type of " + type + " is not valid. Valid types = SET, GET");
    }

  }
```

ListIQProvider:

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.IQ;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.provider.IQProvider;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;

public class ListIQProvider implements IQProvider
{
@Override
 public IQ parseIQ(XmlPullParser parser) throws Exception
 {
    ListIQ iq = new ListIQ();
    boolean done = false;

    String val = "", id = "", ts = "";
    while (!done)
    {
        int eventType = parser.next();
        if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
        {
            if (parser.getName().equals("point"))
            {
                val = parser.getAttributeValue("", "val");
                id = parser.getAttributeValue("", "id");
                ts = parser.getAttributeValue("", "ts");
                iq.addChat(new ListIQ.Chat(val, id, ts));
            }

        }
        else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG)
        {
            if (parser.getName().equals("control"))
            {
                done = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return iq;
 }
}
```

ListIQ:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.IQ;
public class ListIQ extends IQ
{

 private List<Chat> chats;

 public ListIQ()
 {
    this.chats = new ArrayList<ListIQ.Chat>();
 }

 public void addChat(Chat chat)
 {
    chats.add(chat);
 }

 public List<Chat> getChats()
 {
    return chats;
 }

 @Override
 public String getChildElementXML()
 {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("<control xmlns=\"http://domain_name.com/powertalk/control/2.0\">");
    for (Chat chat : chats)
    {
        builder.append(chat.toXml());
    }
    builder.append("</control>");
    return builder.toString();
 }

 public static class Chat 
 {
    private String id;
    private String val;
    private String ts;

    public Chat(String val, String id, String ts)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.val = val;
        this.ts = ts;
    }

    public String getID()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setID(String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getVal()
    {
        return val;
    }

    public void setVal(String val)
    {
        this.val = val;
    }
    public String getTS()
    {
        return ts;
    }

    public void setTS(String ts)
    {
        this.ts = ts;
    }

    public String toXml()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("<point val=\"");
        builder.append(val).append("\"");
        builder.append(" id=\"");
        builder.append(id).append("\"");
        builder.append(" ts=\"");
        builder.append(ts);
        builder.append("\"/>");
        return builder.toString();
    }

 }
}
```

ServiceProviders:

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.provider.ProviderManager;

public class ServiceProviders 
{
    public static void Register_Providers(ProviderManager pm)
    {
        pm.addIQProvider("control", "http://domain_name.com/powertalk/control/2.0", new ListIQProvider());

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on smack 4.1.8 and am now trying with smack 3.2.1 and have modified my code. I can see that my entire stanza is sent and received as expected.

My code just returns the first line of the stanza:

```
<iq id="123" to="user@xmppserver.domain.net/Smack" from="sandbox@xmppserver.domain.net/0004a369d964" type="result"></iq>
```

I enabled smack debugger and I can see the entire result stanza in the debugger window.

How do I get the rest?

I am expecting:

```
<iq from="sandbox@xmppserver.domain/resource" type="result"to="rmorgan@xmppserver.domain/resource" id="123"
<controlxmlns="http://domain.com/powertalk/control/2.0">
<point val="0" id="00000000/relay_1A" ts="2016-08-30T15:52:41.068308Z"/>
<point val="0" id="00000000/relay_2A" ts="2016-08-30T15:52:41.148337Z"/>
</control>
</iq>
```

here is my code:

```
            final XMPPConnection mConnection = this.getConnection();
            this.login();

            IQConnectionRequest iq = new IQConnectionRequest("00000000/relay_1A", "00000000/relay_1A");

            iq.setTo("sandbox@xmppserver.domain.net/0004a369d964");
            iq.setFrom("user@xmppserver.domain.net");
            iq.setPacketID("123");
            iq.setType(IQ.Type.GET);

            PacketFilter filter = new AndFilter(new PacketIDFilter(iq.getPacketID()),
                    new PacketTypeFilter(IQ.class));
            PacketCollector collector = mConnection.createPacketCollector(filter);
            // Send the iq packet with an invalid namespace
            mConnection.sendPacket(iq);

            IQ result = (IQ)collector.nextResult(50000);
            // Stop queuing results
            collector.cancel();             

            System.out.println("result.getType () = " + result.toXML());

            }
```